# htaccess issue with seo friendly urls - GoDaddy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

OK, I'm looking to use mod rewrite to write seo friendly urls for my site. It works fine on my xampp local testing server. However, I'm having problems when trying to put it live, it doesn't seem to work at all.

Here's what I've written in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ category.php?location=$1
```

So the idea is to change `mysite.com/category.php?location=london`to `mysite.com/category/london`.

Initially I though it may be an issue with the ability to mod rewrite being switched on on GoDaddy's end, so I contacted GoDaddy to see if it that was the case and their response was that: "Mod_rewrite is an Apache Web server module installed on all of our Linux servers by default; it does not have to be installed or enabled. Our Linux hosting accounts support most mod_rewrite functions. Because enabling mod_rewrite is handled at a global level, you do not need to enable it in your httpd.conf file. You only need to add the desired code to the body of your .htaccess file."

And they bascially implied that the error is not with them and with my code. I'm not very experienced with mod rewrites and it seemed to work fine when I wrote it like this on other servers. Is there something special you have to write with godaddy? Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is that all in your htaccess file? What error do you get when visiting a desired URL, is it a 500 Internal Server error?

What I usualy add by default is an If-statement:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?location=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

By the way, note the `_-` at the end of the charset in the rule, for instance New York has a SEF version which is `new-york`, `category/new-york` would fail in your RewriteRule.

Comment: Yeah, that's all there is in my htaccess file. And I get a 404 not found page. I tried your code and it hasn't worked. I'm still getting 404 not found. :(

Comment: are you sure category.php is in the same directory as the htaccess? 404 file not found isn't a htaccess error..

Comment: Yeah it's in the same directory. It comes up with a white screen with:

"Not Found

The requested URL /category/london was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Hmm, ok. Than it does simply bypas your rewriterules since the error states it is looking for the directories category/london.. Strange.

Comment: I finally got this to work by the way. I just had to add `Options -MultiViews` before RewriteEngine on. Thanks for your help all the same!